# How can pinch zoom my image which showing from viewpager adapter

Tags: android, gridview, zooming, swipe, pinch

Hey guys i am trying to create a IMAGE gallery, but i am having trouble in pinch zoom my image Gestures,after the user will clicked the image open new activity and show that image its working like as swipe selected image but i want to pinch zoom selected image, how can i do that?

please help guys...thanks in advance..

this is the Main Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set title for the GridView
        setTitle("GridView");
        // Get the view from grid_view.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_view);

        // Set the images from ImageAdapter.java to GridView
        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        // Listening to GridView item click
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                // Launch ImageViewPager.java on selecting GridView Item
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ImageViewPager.class);

                // Show a simple toast message for the item position
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // Send the click position to ImageViewPager.java using intent
                i.putExtra("id", position);

                // Start ImageViewPager
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    // Not using options menu for this tutorial
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Also here is my ImageAdapter code:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // Create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // If it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
           // imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // References to our images in res > drawable
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.ar10, R.drawable.ar11, R.drawable.ar12, R.drawable.ar13, R.drawable.ar15, R.drawable.ar16,
            R.drawable.ar17, R.drawable.ar18, R.drawable.ar19, R.drawable.ar20, R.drawable.ar21, R.drawable.ar22, R.drawable.ar23, R.drawable.ar24,
            R.drawable.ar25, R.drawable.ar26, R.drawable.ar28, R.drawable.ar29, R.drawable.ar30
    };
}
```

Also here is my ImagePagerAdapter code:

```
public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private List<ImageView> images;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(List<ImageView> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = images.get(position);
        container.addView(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView(images.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return view == o;
    }
}
```

Also here is my ImageViewPager code:

```
public class ImageViewPager extends Activity {
    // Declare Variable
    int position;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set title for the ViewPager
        setTitle("ViewPager");
        // Get the view from view_pager.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.view_pager);

        // Retrieve data from MainActivity on item click event
        Intent p = getIntent();
        position = p.getExtras().getInt("id");

        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        List<ImageView> images = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

        // Retrieve all the images
        for (int i = 0; i < imageAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[i]);
           // imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
            images.add(imageView);
        }

        // Set the images into ViewPager
        ImagePagerAdapter pageradapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(images);
        ViewPager viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewpager.setAdapter(pageradapter);
        // Show images following the position
        viewpager.setCurrentItem(position);

    }
}
```

Also please how can reduces margin between images

its showing like

[marginTop or marginbutton in gridview images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCTjF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

checkout com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:'actualVersion'
I use this library to do zoom images

Comment: i know about it but no have idea that how can implement